# Core Data Spotlight Integration in iOS

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios, spotlight

I'm developping an ios (3.1.3) application to manage contacts, tasks, activities, etc. These models are managed by core data and it works very well. Now I want to make all these items searchable in the spotlight search bar in iOS.

Is that possible?

And if so, how to code it? I found the "Core Data Spotlight Integration Programming Guide" but it's not suitable for iOS and I don't find any document or tutorial related to what I want.

Any ideas, suggestions? or full solution! :D

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will be possible from iOS 9 onwards.
Apple just released a CoreSpotlight framework at WWDC 2015, and with integration its possible to search contents within third party apps and much more.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW3)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot integrate your application with Spotlight in iOS for now, there's no API to do it.

You can file a radar and wish an new Spotlight API in iOS 5?

Answer (score 2):

Global search spanning all apps was a core feature of PalmOS going way back to PalmOS version 2.0, if I recall correctly.  Yet even today, Apple's iOS Spotlight Search still only supports the built in apps provided by Apple.

It is shameful that Apple hasn't opened this up to developers yet - it would make Spotlight so much more useful on the iPhone and iPad.

Comment: PalmOS 2.0 was introduced in 1997.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do it with iOS9 Search.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW3